# What does this icon (screenshot) in status bar mean?

Tags: notification-icons

(First, yes, I did RTFM and so my homework is done.)

My phone shows this [image: Screenshot of my phone's status bar] icon.

I looked into the manual of my phone, it lists about 20 status bar icons, but this one isn't among them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the icon represents enabled 'Data Saver', which should also prevent background data transfers.